# Undefined "element" in $animation for ng-view "leave" callback

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I posted this on the Angular.js 's google group but doesn't seem to get attention or help. So I re-post it here.

Issue: When loading a new partial html into ng-view, the "enter" callback's element is defined and correct, but the old partial html (which is supposed to be replaced by the new one) is NOT gone, instead the new content is appended under the old content, let alone any sliding animation. I check the log, the "element" in both "leave" $animation's setup and start functions appears as undefined, which caused some jquery error.

I also tried the css way of defining similar animations, but lack of any luck - no animations, no errors. (I have seen demo here http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive:ngView, so it might be due to some mis-configuration I had which I couldn't figured out still)

The plunker is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/wSsjSPN62PyKHJAQtvfv

Comment: did you try using pure css3 solution with css-transition

Answer (score 0):

There were a few issues with your plunker, but I think they may just have been setup issues, not your code.

First one - jQuery wasn't included, this caused issues with the element returning undefined.

Secondly, you need to set additional CSS to see transitions.

See updated example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/gmA1kVOpX2lk94AWs2pJ?p=preview

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.js"></script>
```